# vscode - tsconfig.json's files cannot resolve file without extention

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tsconfig, tsx

I have a `tsconfig.json` inside my project directory and the `files` is configured as following:

```
"files": ["src/index"],
```

I got error frmo VS Code saying:

```
File '/Volumes/Unix/Workplace/ProjectXXX/src/index' not found.
```

If I just change to this:

```
"files": ["src/index.tsx"],
```

Everything works.

I would like to know, is it necessary that I have to provide to explicit file extension for `tsconfig.json`?

Or is it a bug inside VS Code that it cannot auto recognize files with `.ts`, `.tsx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files property expects a list of files, and so they must have extensions. The files property will cause TSC to only analyze those files explicitly listed.

If you want to analyze an entire subdirectory it would probably be better to use the `includes` property.

[The TypeScript documentation of tsconfig is worth a read](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)